# How to write a controller in Symfony2 to edit content with Jeditable

Tags: symfony, jeditable

I'm using jeditable plugin for JavaScript and I want to implement it in my Symfony2 project. I want to edit a name with the plugin and that name to be edited in the database, too, not the change to be gone when I refresh the page, but in my case, it's gone. :(

I'm almost sure that the controller shouldn't be in that way and the problem is from it, but how exactly to write it? Here it is:

```
public function editCategoryAction(Request $request, $id)
{   
    $category = $this->repository->find($id);      
    $form = $this->createForm(new CategoryType(), $category);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $this->em->persist($category);
            $this->em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('categories'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render(
        'AcmeBudgetTrackerBundle:Categories:categories.html.twig', array( 
            'form' => $form->createView()));      
}
```

This is my **template**:

```
    <a href="{{ path('edit_category', { 'id': cat.id}) }}">
        <strong class="edit">
            {{ cat.name }}
        </strong>
    </a> 

<script>
    var token = "{{form._token.vars.value}}";
    var path = "{{ path('edit_category', { 'id': cat.id}) }}";
</script>
```

And this is in the **.js file**:

```
(function(){
     $('.edit').editable(function (value, settings) {
            var data = {};
            data[this.id] = value;
            data["_token"] = token;
            console.log(path);
            console.log(data);
            $.post(path, data);
                return(value);
            }, {
                indicator:'Saving...'
            });
}) ();
```

The output in the console looks fine:

```
/BudgetTracker/web/app_dev.php/edit_category/52
Object {: "Edu", _token: "9d29860b59ccafbc265ea12346c91fa7e378cc97"}
```

but the problem is that nothing is posted to the database and when I hit refresh the change I made is gone.

Can you please help me to solve this? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I'm using jeditable with sonata, but little difference in my code, I'm not using symfony form (but I guess I should) and I'm using the default editable with url instead of function (and I think you should) because it handle the data sending with ajax instead of doing it yourself. So I think you should check if you go through the isValid() first, and remove the return redirect since you are doing ajax and you don't want redirection.

Comment: And btw, what's the purpose of your <a href></a>? Isn't it messing with jeditable?

Comment: <a href> is there because I don't know how to say the id of the element I'm editing in another way.

Comment: Then remove the <a href></a> tag and add id="{{ cat.id }}" in your <strong> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to use the form component here, you only want to handle a string. So I'll explain a way to do.

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.edit').editable(path);
```

**Controller:**

```
public function editCategoryAction(Category $category)
{   
    //check if exists/valid

    //get the text sent from jeditable
    $name = $this->request->get('value');
    $category->setName($name);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($category);
    $em->flush();
    //return the name value to jeditable so it can display it
    return new Response($name);     
}
```

**Twig:**

```
<strong class="edit">{{ cat.name }}</strong>

<script>
    var path = "{{ path('edit_category', { 'id': cat.id}) }}";
</script>
```

jEditable sends edited text named as 'value', so you can get it in the controller. In your controller, you implicitly use paramconverter to get the category from the id in the URL. And that should be OK now.

Note that you can use FORJsRoutingBundle, if you want to avoid mixing twig with javascript in order to access path.

Comment: I edited it in the way you said, but nothing changed :( Still when I hit refresh the old data is seen.

Comment: Can you debug and tell me what is sent and what is returned?

Comment: Well it first gave me some errors for example that $this->response wasn't found, but when I fixed them, the console is empty and says nothing, the name is edited until a hit refresh, and then it becomes with its old value again.

Comment: Did you copy what I wrote? coz I forgot the persist/flush at start, I just edited this.

Comment: Yes :$ I did. It's working perfectly now! I don't know how to thank you! I really appreciate your help! :)